# Show that $\langle a\rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $\langle a,b\rangle$ where $a$ and $b$ are permutations

Tags: group-theory, permutations, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

I'm studying for an exam and in a previous year we had the question:

> Let $a=(12345678)$, and $b=(26)(48)$ and $G=\langle a,b \rangle$. Show that $\langle a \rangle$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and by considering $G/\langle a \rangle$ determine $|G|$.

I have the solution for this, which I need some help understanding. It goes like this:

Clearly $\langle a \rangle ^a = \langle a \rangle$ (ok, no problem. I know it must be closed), it is sufficient to show that $\langle a \rangle ^b = \langle a \rangle$. By direct calculation we have that $bab^{-1}=a^5 \in \langle a \rangle$ so $\langle a \rangle$ is normal.

I don't quite get this "direct calculation" bit.

Does it mean I'm supposed to get $(26)(48)(12345678)(62)(84) = (16385274)$ and then magically figure out this is $a^5$ (I didn't verify the last statement)?

It carries on: Since $a^ib\langle a \rangle = ba^{5i}\langle a \rangle = b \langle a \rangle$ (ok, I get it... if it's normal this is true) it follows that $G/\langle a \rangle = \langle a \rangle$, $b\langle a \rangle$ and so $|G/\langle a \rangle|=2$ (I realise $G/\langle a \rangle = g\langle a \rangle$, and since $G=\langle a, b\rangle$ then $G/\langle a \rangle=b\langle a \rangle$... not sure where the 2 came from). Since $|\langle a \rangle|=8$ (how do I know this?) it follows that $|G| = 16$.

Thanks!

Comment: For your question "Does it mean I'm supposed to ...", the answer is yes, that is exactly what you are supposed to do. You know that $bab^{-1}$ will be a power of $a$, so the question is which power, and the fact that $a$ maps $1$ to $6$ tells you that it must be $a^5$ (because $a^2$ maps $1$ to $3$, $a^3$ maps $1$ to $4$, etc.).

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt! (btw, I can't believe you answered my dummy question... your computational group theory book is on my pile of what to read after my exams! )